# sed/awk - Put all text on the same line as a preceding number

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I get all text that proceeds 'number:number' onto the same line as the preceding 'number:number'?

```
10:15
text line one 
text line two
text no pattern

11:12
random text
text is random 
totally random
could be four lines 
could be five
```

Should then become

```
10:15 text line one text line two text no pattern
11:12 random text text is random totally random could be four lines could be five
```

Comment: Will the text ever have any numbers in it?

Comment: No it will only be text or things line commas and stops

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for your example-

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt | sed 's/[0-9]*:[0-9]*/\n&/g'
```

Explanation-

tr will initially put everything on the same line.

Then that sed one liner will insert new lines before each num:num pattern.

Comment: That will only work with some seds due to non-portable use of `\n`, will insert newlines before any `:` that isn't surrounded by digits, and will insert an unwanted newline at the start of the output.

Answer (score 2):

Given that input file all you need is to tell awk to read a blank-line-separated paragraph at a time using `RS=<null>` and recompile each record using the default `OFS` value of a blank char

```
$ awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' file
10:15 text line one text line two text no pattern
11:12 random text text is random totally random could be four lines could be five
```

Comment: This answer, while it works, completely ignores the point of using the num:num pattern as a distinguishing feature. It would have been nicer if you'd used that pattern as a way to generate the breaks.

Comment: That's like saying when someone asks how to dig a hole using a toothbrush when they have a shovel next to them you should tell them how to do it with the toothbrush instead of with the shovel. People who ask questions don't know the right way to do things or they wouldn't be asking. They benefit much more from being shown the right approach than the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Both sed and awk solutions join lines till a new record is detected or input is done in which case the joined lines are printed and cleared - use either solution

the sed oneliner

```
sed -nr '/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/!{H;$!b}; x; s/\n/ /gp'
```

the awk script

```
awk '
!/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ {
  lines=lines" "$0
  next
}
{if(lines) print lines; lines=$0}
END {print lines}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an GNU AWK script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { RS = "\n[0-9]+:[0-9]+|\n$" }
      { gsub(/\n/,"",$0)
        printf( "%s%s ", $0,RT) }
```

Use it like this `awk -f script.awk file.txt`

It uses the GNU AWK specific extensions `RT` and regex `RS`:

- the record separator is set to "colon separated number pairs".
- to get the final newline at the end of the file the "|\n$" is added to match the last newline in the file.
- In order to start separation at the second pair: the "\n" is added in front. Thus the first colon separated number pair "10:15" is included in the first `$0` and not in `RT`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that you want to split the file on paragraphs instead of lines.  In awk, if you set RS="" it enables paragraph mode.  Each iteration of the awk loop will have a paragraph in $0.  You can then substitute the newlines and turn them into spaces.

```
awk  <data.txt 'BEGIN { RS = "" ; FS = "\n" } { gsub(/\n/, " ", $0) ; print }'
```

Output:

```
10:15 text line one  text line two text no pattern
11:12 random text text is random  totally random could be four lines  could be five
```

The benefit of this is that awk handles all the special cases for you: files that end in a blank line, end without a blank line, end without a newline, etc.